# Hadoop maven dependency error - hadoop classes are not found

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, jar, dependencies

Despite I import following dependencies into my pom, related Hadoop classes `(org.apache.hadoop.*)` are not imported.

```
<properties>
<hadoop.version>1.0.4</hadoop.version>
</properties>


<!-- Apache Hadoop Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-examples</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-tools</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I could as well not manage to access any of those .hadoop packages regardless of the dependencies i defined - i guess this thing is broken from a Maven point of view ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below pom to have Hadoop dependencies resolved for the project.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>cloudera</id>
        <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<properties>
    <hadoop-version>2.0.0-cdh4.2.0</hadoop-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-datajoin</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-app</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: did not work.. getting errorr while importing Hadoop classes. `(org.apache.hadoop.*)` When I inspect jars in the maven repository, I recognize that all of them are broken.

Comment: See if your are connected to internet while running the mvn

Comment: Did you copy the repository url? If you see the link https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-annotations/2.0.0-cdh4.2.0/ you can see the jars available. So it should ideally get downloaded.

Comment: yes, I copied it from your pom. I deleted all related content inside maven repository and re-imported maven resources through IntelliJ Idea 13 maven plugin; it is still same.

Answer (score 0):

I work with following dependencies in a hadoop simple test application:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: despite I **deleted all related content** inside maven repository and **re-imported maven resources** through **IntelliJ Idea 13** maven plugin; it is still same.