# Maven dependency in hadoop

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, dependencies, rebuild

I can't import the ***NameNode*** class which is inside **hadoop-hdfs-project**  from the class ***TextOutputFormat*** which is inside **hadoop-mapreduce-project**.
If I need to add dependency in pom.xml file, how?

I added **import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode** in **TextOutputFormat** class.

I got ***package does not exist*** error while I rubuild the code using **maven**.

Comment: tried for 20 minutes did not find said class in any of the hadoop dependencies :/
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2 should contain it but i cannot access anything from that dependencie.

Comment: A similar question without any solutions - i guess that hadoop thing is broken from a maven point of view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168400/hadoop-maven-dependency-error-hadoop-classes-are-not-found

Comment: **_hadoop version is- 2.6.0 (YARN)_**.I need to access some Static variables of **NameNode**class (hdfs-project) form **TextOutputFormat** class(mapreduce-client-core).Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately i dont know about hadoop but Maven only (hence i tried to identify working dependencies to access NameNode) - If it is a possibility you could download the jars manually (i found various posts stating that the Maven jars of the depenencies seem to be corrupted - i have however not verified that information) - so best i can do is give you the upvote for further attention ;)